# Avoiding multipe if-else for sql query building java

Tags: java

Not sure if this has been ever answered on the forum. Question is how to avoid multiple if-else statements in a java code for progressive query building based on input received.

Example below:

I have a search form on the UI against which a query has to be run. The UI form has multiple parameters. For example: if searching for a  employee/employees, one can search using Name (wild card), salary group, office location etc. User can fill this search form in any combination.

The back end sql query has multiple join tables example: employee, salarygroups, offices etc

The data is being transferred to the server code using an json.. something like

```
    "filterRequest"
     {
         "employeeName": String,
         "salaryGroup": String,
         "offices": String
     }
```

Above is just an example and in actuality I have about 10 parameters that can be used for search.
The problem is I am at present writing multiple if else statements to check if these parameters are being passed and building my SQL query accordingly something like

```
     if(filterRequest.getEmployeeName()!=null){
     sqlQuery.append("and emp.employeeName like (:employeeName)");
     }
     if(filterRequest.getSalaryGroup()!=null){
     sqlQuery.append("and sal.getSalaryGroup like (:salaryGroup)");
     }


     return sqlQuery;
```

Comment: You might want to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but check their help pages first to see if it is on-topic and how to write the question correctly.

Comment: https://github.com/keijack/hql-generator check this project.

Comment: Check "Hibernate query by example" and "Hibernate specifications". they might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a method to check and add the sqlPart. For example like this:

```
addSqlPart(sqlQuery, filterRequest, FilterRequest::getEmployeeName, "and emp.employeeName like (:employeeName)");
addSqlPart(sqlQuery, filterRequest, FilterRequest::getSalaryGroup, "and emp.salaryGroup like (:salaryGroup)");
```

Method which checks if the given getter has a value and adds the sqlPart if so

```
    private static void addSqlPart(StringBuffer sqlQuery, FilterRequest filterRequest, Function<FilterRequest, Object> getter, String sqlPart) {
        Object value = getter.apply(filterRequest);
        if (value != null) {
            sqlQuery.append(sqlPart);
        }
    }
```